# Numpy random functions create inconsistent shapes for given argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I found an odd behavior of numpy's [random number generators](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matlib.rand.html).
It seems that they do not generate consistent matrix shapes for a given argument.
It is just super annoying to spend an extra line for conversion afterward which I'd like to circumvent.
How can I tell `matlib.randn` directly to generate a vector of size `(200,)`?

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((200,))
B = np.matlib.randn((200,))
print(A.shape)    # prints (200,)
print(B.shape)    # prints (1, 200)
```

Comment: Do you need to use the `matlib` version for some special reason?

Comment: No, I was just using it because of consistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.random` instead of `numpy.matlib`:

```
numpy.random.randn(200).shape # prints (200,)
```

[`numpy.random.randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html) can create any shape, whereas [`numpy.matlib.randn`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matlib.randn.html) always creates a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

B is a [matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) object, not a [ndarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html). The matrix object doesn't have an 1D equivalent objects and are not recommended to use anymore, so you should use `np.random.random` instead.